# How to rename while downloading file?

Tags: vue.js, download, vuetify.js

Use `window.location.href` i can not rename file

Use `<a href='' download=''></a>` but it doesn't work

```
<v-flex>
    <div>
        <a :href="props.url" :download="props.item.name">下载</a>
    </div>
</v-flex>
```

Rename while downloading file

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a file while still downloading is not possible as it would break the download. Virtually any os will forbid you to do that.

What you can do:

1) Rename the file before downloading and save it with the new name like so:

`<a href="path_to_file" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a>`

So you were right already, only you are missing the detail that you can freely name the file and do not have to stick to the `props.item.name`.

2) Let the download finish and then rename it.

Comment: How to implement the first one？